# json object in ajax jquery request

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have the following HTTP request workload

```
  {jsonObj={"Nids":"<Id>20</Id><Id>22</Id>","Mids":"\"<Id>337</Id><Id>330</Id><Id>333</Id><Id>335</Id><Id>328</Id>\"","PageNo":"\"3\""}}
```

I have the following error
Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JSON. Try:

```
{jsonObj:{"Nids":"<Id>20</Id><Id>22</Id>","Mids":"\"<Id>337</Id><Id>330</Id><Id>333</Id><Id>335</Id><Id>328</Id>\"","PageNo":"\"3\""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `jsonObj=` with `jsonObj:`

Notice `:` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

The JsonObj is not valid. The below works.

Use `JSON.stringify` as much as possible.

```
> obj='{"jsonObj":{"Nids":"<Id>20</Id><Id>22</Id>","Mids":"<Id>337</Id><Id>330</Id><Id>333</Id><Id>335</Id><Id>328</Id>","PageNo":"3"}}'
'{"jsonObj":{"Nids":"<Id>20</Id><Id>22</Id>","Mids":"<Id>337</Id><Id>330</Id><Id>333</Id><Id>335</Id><Id>328</Id>","PageNo":"3"}}'
> JSON.parse(obj)
{ jsonObj:
   { Nids: '<Id>20</Id><Id>22</Id>',
     Mids: '<Id>337</Id><Id>330</Id><Id>333</Id><Id>335</Id><Id>328</Id>',
     PageNo: '3' } }
>
```